“I know what’s best but I do the opposite” translation?
A while ago I saw a video with a girl carrying a keychain that had the latin translation of “I know what’s best but I do the opposite”. I can’t find the girl again nor can I find a translation of this online. Does anyone know the translation?

According to the original the tiktok, CNread's answer is right.

This is likely translating lines 20-21 in book 7 of Ovid's Metamorphoses, recounting the story of Jason and Medea:

video meliora proboque,
deteriora sequor.


I see and approve of what's better, (but) I follow what's worse.


That sounds like what Paul said in Romans 7:15:

Quod volo hoc ago sed quod odi illud facio.


I do not do what I want, but I do the very thing I hate.

Or Romans 7:19:

Non enim quod volo bonum, hoc facio: sed quod nolo malum, hoc ago.


For the good which I will, I do not; but the evil which I will not,
that I do.


This must surely be the more well-known reference, rather than the one by Ovid.

@R.P.: Why do you think so? Paul probably took it from Ovid?

@Cerberus: No literary work has had more impact on modern civilization than the Holy Scriptures. And, no, the Apostle Paul wasn't showing off his scholarship. He was speaking of his personal struggle with sin.

@ExpeditoBipes: Why would he not have been influenced by Ovid?

@Cerberus: To suppose that the Apostle Paul, writing under the inspiration of the Holy Spirit, couldn't articulate his own personal experience without the help of Ovid strikes me as extremely farfetched. What makes you so sure he "probably" took it from Ovid when the wording isn't even similar?

@ExpeditoBipes: I don't think this is the place for a religious discussion.

@Cerberus  As a Christian I'm happy if Paul did or didn't have input from Ovid. This isn't meant to be a "religious" comment except to say that I find it easy to imagine that some of Paul's allusions were based on other material and some not. God knows which is which. Fortunately :-). His seemingly unfortunate allusion to Cretans  & slow bellys he acknowledges as largely quoted.  (A Cretan said it :-) ) . His "in who we live and breathe and have our being" seems to have been based on 600+ year old precedent  - and if his hearers knew of it they would have thought favourably of the reference.

It doesn't strike me as terribly unlikely that Paul would have been aware of classics such as Ovid. All writers are influenced by things they have read and heard. It sounds quite reasonable to me to think that Paul was influenced by Ovid to some degree, but that degree may well have been very small. Being influenced by earlier writers doesn't make Paul bad in any sense.

@JoonasIlmavirta: You seem to be missing the point. Imagine someone hesitating when handed a piece of bread, and then the person offering it said, "Don't worry. I washed my hands." Would you then conclude that he was probably influenced by Pontius Pilate? Isn't it much more likely that he was just expressing something that actually happened?

What if Ovid had never written that? Should we suppose that Paul wouldn't have been able to articulate his experience, and Romans 7 would have been left without that part?

Getting literary influence is far from being unable to express the same sentiment on one's own. I can quote Star Wars and say "I have a bad feeling about this", but I would also be able to express the idea without those movies having been made. I'm not saying that Paul must have been trying to mimic Ovid and owes this phrase to him; I actually find it likely that the similarity is mostly coincidental. That is, I expect the degree of influence (cf. my previous comment) to have been small, as with almost all instances of hands being washed.

I must say that I was totally unaware of the Ovid quote. I've never seen it referenced before, or not that I recall, while I've seen the Paul verse quoted many times, also outside of any religious context. Coupled with the fact that the Bible has been read and perhaps more significantly heard by billions of people continuously over 2000 years, and the additional fact that reading the classics is mostly a hobby of the intellectual elite, this made me think that the Paul quote is the more likely source. But I don't know, of course.

@R.P. I think it says more about what circles one runs in. I had the opposite experience as you, but I do not regularly consume Christian media.

@R.P. Check the comment on the question. Turns out it was a quote of Ovid after all.

@cmv I see, I guess I was wrong then. Thank you for the heads-up!
